# Listening to plugin events in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on Eclipse ide. I want to know how an action done on one plugin can be listened by other plugins so that they can also handle the same event.

Please do reply if you have anything...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [**eclipse plugin architecture**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Plug-in-architecture/plugin_architecture.html#5.) article

[image: Listener Extension]

> In the listener extension pattern, the host plug-in acts as the subject of the observation, and extender plug-ins act as the observers or listeners.
>   The host plug-in therefore provides an extension-point that may be called listeners, and a corresponding interface that may be called `IListener`.
>   Each extender plug-in then extends the listeners extension-point by supplying a specific listener that implements the IListener interface, or by supplying a sequence of such listeners.
>
> Because the listeners are then specified declaratively through the plug-in extension mechanism, these listeners can be automatically registered for event notification by extension processing.
>   The first time notification is required, the subject plug-in processes its listeners members, and for each member, instantiates a specific listener callback object and registers that listener for event notification.